# clearInterval does not work in my JS code

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I've spent quite sometime trying to figure this out. I understand there are multiple questions online and stackoverflow where this issue is resolved, I've tried to do exactly the same thing in my case however I seem to run into the issue where clearInterval does not work.

My code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="FlashText()">Flash</button>
        <span style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" id="showText">Flash Text</span>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 function FlashText()
 {
      var timer = setInterval(blink_text,1000);

      $.ajax({
       
           url: some url,
           success: function(){
                $('#showText').text("Other Text");
               clearInterval(timer);

           }
      })
 }

function blink_text()
  {
      $('#showText').fadeOut(750);
      $('#showText').fadeIn(750);
  }
```

I click the button and I see that the text is flashing. Upon success, i used `Debugger;` to look at the `timer` and it shows a value of `19`. I step through this line, and nothing happens.

The text changes to `Other Text` and it just keeps flashing.

I've looked at the console in Developer Tools and there is no errors whatsoever. I know that `timer` is not out of scope as i use this within the same function. Everything seems to be exactly like it should. Yet it is not working. What could be the issue?

The goal is to keep the text flashing until I get the `Success` from my `ajax` call in which case I want to change the text to `Other Text` and stop fadeIn/Out.

Comment: Can you check the browser you are using - The browser supported by clearTimeout() & clearInterval() Method are listed here:
1. Google Chrome 1.0,
2. Internet Explorer 4.0,
3. Firefox 1.0,
4. Opera 4.0,
5. Safari 1.0

Comment: @Purvisingh - About Chrome shows : Version 92.0.4515.107

Comment: You Fire the Timer every second but the flashing takes 1.5 seconds. So if your Ajax call takes 5 seconds flashing will last for 2.5 more second till it stops

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - you are correct sir. There is a few second delay that takes place. As an alternative, would there be another way to stop the flashing immediately as soon as the Ajax call is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to use css to make the text flash

```
.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
 }
```

And then add and remove class

```
function FlashText()
{
  $('#showText').addClass(‘blink_me’);

  $.ajax({
   
       url: some url,
       success: function(){
            $('#showText').reomveClass(‘blink_me’).text("Other Text");         
       }
  })
```

}